# Create non-english windows explorer right-click menu

Tags: windows, registry, file-association

[How to Add Any Application Shortcut to Windows Explorer’s Context Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

InstallShield can create registry during installation but I can't create non-english registry successfully.

tested .reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\作業用]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\作業用\command]
@="C:\My Menu\Menu.exe "%1""
```

1st line command can create
2nd line command can't create

Isn't anyway to create a non-english shortcut e.g. .reg or programming?

Comment: You can try saving the .reg file with different Encoding in Notepad or Notepad++

Comment: @sstan, use installshield build vb.net program, when create setup file with non-english registry not successfully so have to create separate .reg for installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a chosen term with latin letters for the command and specify the text to display to the user as the default value of that key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\yourword]
@="作業用"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\yourword\command]
@="\"C:\\My Menu\\Menu.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Be sure to save the *.reg file with Encoding "Unicode with BOM".

Also remember to escape the values in double quotes: \ must be written as \\. Double quotes " must be written as \".

Also: If there are spaces within the path of your executable, you need to enclose the path in double quotes (escaped with \)